# How to iterate over multiple dictionaries within a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dictionaries named 'I' and 'J' and I want to iterate it over a for loop and get the value of a variable which is function of both 'I' and 'J'.

```
I={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150}
J={-50,-40,-30,-20,-10,0,10,20,30,40}

F=[[0 for j in J] for i in I]


for i in I:
    for j in J:
        if i+j==100:
            F[i][j]=-j*2.782490319
        else:
            F[i][j]="NA"

print(F[60][40])
```

I want the value in the print command to be taken from dictionary 'I' & 'J'. For example in above code I have written print(F[60][40]), so the 60 can be any value from dictionary 'I' and 40 can be any value from dictionary 'J'.

I was expecting the answer for above code to be "-111.29961276" but instead I am getting an error "IndexError: list index out of range".
I would be more than happy if somebody could answer the query. TIA :)

Comment: You have two `set` objects

Comment: Hey you mean the I and J right? would you mind elaborating a bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as mentioned, `I` and `J` are sets, but the problem is that `F` is a list.

try this:

```py
I={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150}
J={-50,-40,-30,-20,-10,0,10,20,30,40}

F={(i,j):0 for j in J for i in I}


for i in I:
    for j in J:
        if i+j==100:
            F[(i,j)]=-j*2.782490319
        else:
            F[(i,j)]="NA"

print(F[(60,40)])
```

I changed F to be a dictionary with keys of type `(int, int)`, and that's it...

Output:

> -111.29961276

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. I appreciate your quick response, thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Saurabh if thise solves your problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: Yes, it did solve my problem. I am sorry, I am pretty new here, would you please tell me what do you mean by accepting the answer?

Comment: @Saurabh, he means the green check mark, like you just marked. bruno - thanks for asking :)